# How to stop code from displaying on everypage

Tags: html, css

Hi I have very little coding experience and im very new to this so sorry if this is a silly question. I've been messing around with it but i cant figure out how to stop this code from displaying across all pages:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<body id="imageslide"
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 100%;
      margin: auto;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" >
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://d2a2wjuuf1c30f.cloudfront.net/product_photos/41163636/gg_201_original.jpg" alt="Chania" width="980" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="https://d1nr5wevwcuzuv.cloudfront.net/product_photos/40913430/gg1_original.jpg" alt="Chania" width="980" height="345">
      </div>


    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
<br>
<br>

<html>
<body>

<body>
<div class="imageslide">
<div style="background-color:#FFC3C3; color:white; padding:1px; text-align:center;">

<h2>Shop By Category</h2>
</div> 

</body>
</html>

<br>
```

I only want it to display on my websites home page but its appearing on every page. The code is in the layout file as i need it to appear above the page content and sidebar. Im editing the stores html through storenvy if that helps.Is there something i can add to the CSS or html that will stop it coming up on pages other than the homepage. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use two `<html>` tags. A page starts with a `<html>` and ends with a `</html>`.

If you want multiple sections on a page just use `<div>` & `</div>` for start and end of `div`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <body id="imageslide" <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .carousel-inner > .item > img,
      .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
        width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
      }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <br>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="https://d2a2wjuuf1c30f.cloudfront.net/product_photos/41163636/gg_201_original.jpg" alt="Chania" width="980" height="345">
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://d1nr5wevwcuzuv.cloudfront.net/product_photos/40913430/gg1_original.jpg" alt="Chania" width="980" height="345">
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="imageslide">
      <div style="background-color:#FFC3C3; color:white; padding:1px; text-align:center;">

        <h2>Shop By Category</h2>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for cleaning that up I'll keep hat in mind in future! but have you any idea how I can stop it appearing on every page of my website? cheers

Comment: Add snaps of whatever is getting repeated, because I am don't think that's possible.

Comment: thanks for the help I'll link the website to show you :)

Comment: @charlieconorcharlie I didn't see any repetition. Add relevant pictures. *Also links to other site are seen as promotional, so don't post the link.*